# Infinite Sum of Hilbert spaces is coproduct?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_n$ be Hilbert spaces for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then define

$H:=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n$

with inner product

$\langle h,\tilde{h}\rangle_H$ $=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\langle h_n,\tilde{h_n}\rangle_{H_n}$

Then $H$ is again a Hilbert space. Does it satisfy the universal property of the coproduct in the category of Hilbert spaces and maps that are bounded by one. I think the map that we get from the universal property should be of the form

$q(h):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f_n(h_n)$

for maps $f_n:H_n\to T$ with $||f_n||\leq 1$.
My problem is to show that this map is well defined, that is $||q(h)||\leq||h||$. Using the usual estimates for $f_n$, Cauchy schwartz and linearity of the inner product I can only get

$||q(h)||^2\leq \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\langle h_n,h_n\rangle^\frac{1}{2}$

The left hand side is not the norm induced by the inner product I defined above. Can somebody help? Or does it not satisfy the universal property of the coproduct?

Comment: Let $H_1=\Bbb C = H_2$, all other $H_n=0$. Let $f_1=f_2=\mathrm{id}$, then the map you indicate is $\Bbb C^2\to\Bbb C, (x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1+x_2$, which is not a contraction.

Comment: Then does it hold for bounded instead of contractive maps?

Comment: For finite sums, yes. If you allow infinite sums then no, let $H_n=\Bbb C$, $f_n=\mathrm{id}$ for all $n$. Then the map you give is not well defined / continuous.

Comment: The resulting map is not bounded, but it is well defined in the sense that pointwise we obtain an element in $\mathbb{C}$. Maybe does it satisfy the universal property of the coproduct if we allow adjointable maps instead of bounded (as in the case of Hilbert modules)?

Comment: Its not well defined because the element $h_n=\frac1n$ of $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb C$ would get sent to $\sum_n \frac1n$ which is not convergent.